# Models and Database associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to do for me a kind of application for a Writer. Possibility to add chapters, scenes, characters and anecdotes.

My models : chapter, scene, character, anecdote

- Chapter has a number, a title, and has scenes and anecdotes
- Anedote has a subject and one or several themes
- Scene has a text, one or several characters, a place, a period
- Character can appear in on or several scenes

I did the tutorial on Ruby on Rails by Michael Hartl, but I have some difficulties now to implement my model.

Do you know some tutorials on database associations like I want to do, or explanations ?

I hope you understand, and sorry for my bad english

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `Scene has_many: characters` and `Charaker has_many: scenes`. `has_many expects to find a foreign key on associated model and such a key can only point to one parent.

What you need is either:

1. `has_and_belongs_to_many` association
2. `has_many :through` association

Those associations are rather a vast subject to describe in a single question. Please have some reading: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. I strongly recommend reading at least first three chapters and scan the forth before starting designing your models. It is really a pain to realize you have designed extra elaborate database structure which could have been achieved with AR feature you didn't know at the time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm on to try to have a correct database